# Laravel 5.6 ajax request internal server error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Hello i'm developing like disliked system based on https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-laravel-5-like-dislike-system-tutorialexample.html

but the ajax function throwing internal server error

this is my controller

```
public function ajaxRequest(Request $request)
    {
        $post = Post::find($request->id);
        $response = auth()->user()->toggleLiked($post);

        return response()->json(['success' => $response]);
    }
```

and this is my ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });


        $('i.glyphicon-thumbs-up, i.glyphicon-thumbs-down').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).parents(".panel").data('id');
            var c = $('#'+this.id+'-bs3').html();
            var cObjId = this.id;
            var cObj = $(this);


            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'/ajaxRequest',
               data:{id:id},
               success:function(data){
                  if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data.success.attached)){
                    $('#'+cObjId+'-bs3').html(parseInt(c)-1);
                    $(cObj).removeClass("like-post");
                  }else{
                    $('#'+cObjId+'-bs3').html(parseInt(c)+1);
                    $(cObj).addClass("like-post");
                  }
               }
            });


        });


        $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).ekkoLightbox();
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the form for clicking the likes

```
    <span class="pull-right">
       <span class="like-btn">
       <i id="like{{$post->id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up {{ auth()->user()->hasLiked($post) ? 'like-post' : '' }}"></i>
     
       <div id="like{{$post->id}}-bs3">{{ $post->likers()->get()->count() }}</div>
     <span>
   </span>
```

this is the error
"local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toggleLiked does not exist. "

i use  overtrue/laravel-follow package for like and dislike system

what i have done is changing the routes in case it's missing something, but still throwing the same error, what should i do?

ANSWER:

turns out it happens in the controller. its supposed to be toggleLike. meanwhile i type toggleLiked

thank you in advanced

Comment: What is the actual error? Check Laravel log and add the actual error...

Comment: i've found the error it looks like it from a package, i'll edit it, if its not appropriate i will take down my question @Ron kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Laravel version with your project and overtrue/laravel-follow package

Comment: the laravel-follow package works in version 2.1.1 with laravel 5.6 so i just need to composer require overtrue/laravel-follow:2.1.1. that's it!

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you post it with error log.

You can use below commands and try again.

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan config:cache